# Can a hacker bypass UEFI password without changing or restting it?

Tags: passwords, uefi

Can a hacker locally bypass UEFI password without changing or resetting it ?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Every [BIOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BIOS) implementation is quite unique. [UEFI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_Extensible_Firmware_Interface), the successor to BIOS, is a little more standardized, and while I'm not an expert on it, I suspect its security also depends on the implementation. Also note that a boot password is not the same as hardware encryption. A boot password might be vulnerable to some sort of reset, but if your data is encrypted, resetting the startup interface won't help.

Comment: @Adam What i really want to know is if there is some kind of tools (hardware or software) that have been used used to bypass password without resetting it for UEFI systems.

Comment: I don't have an answer to that, just the supposition that you'll need to specify the exact UEFI implementation and version for somebody more expert at that sort of thing to answer.

Answer (score 1):

It's entirely specific to the system, not only in terms of the specific UEFI BIOS implementation that was used, but also to the motherboard. It also depends on which password you're talking about - there could be a supervisor password (stops access to setup/config menus at boot), power-on password, and/or a disk password.

Some vendors are known to have hard-coded service passwords that can get around boot passwords, but these are less common with modern UEFI BIOS implementations, and were never particularly common outside laptops.

Passwords are usually stored in a configuration block on a flash chip on the motherboard, or in an emulated flash region inside the embedded controller (EC). It's common these days for passwords to be hashed - here are [two](https://www.synacktiv.com/en/publications/a-journey-in-reversing-uefi-lenovo-passwords-management.html) [articles](https://jbeekman.nl/blog/2015/03/reverse-engineering-uefi-firmware/) about reverse engineering such implementations. If you reverse engineer the firmware and extract the hashes from where they are stored ([chipsec](https://github.com/chipsec/chipsec) might help there) then you could conceivably crack the password.

Resetting or clearing the password is usually far easier. Some motherboards have a jumper to do it. Some can be cleared using a vendor-provided command line tool, either in the OS or in an EFI/DOS shell environment. There are a few 3rd party tools with similar capabilities, but they're much more common for old legacy BIOS systems than modern UEFI BIOS systems. You can also sometimes clear power on passwords and supervisor passwords by pulling the BIOS battery or clearing its settings with an onboard jumper (historically referred to as "clearing the CMOS").

Disk passwords are a little different - they are usually passed through to a disk that supports the Self Encrypting Drive (SED) standard. This is entirely separate to the UEFI BIOS and a bit too far off topic to discuss here.